# Why my query output misses one row?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

My following query gives output of 72 rows which is correct.

```
SELECT distinct on (st.gid) sv.timing, st.gid, st.area
FROM servers sv
INNER JOIN sites st
ON (st_distance(sv.geom, st.geom)<8.5) where
        sv.workmode = 1 AND sv.timing >= timestamp '2018-02-02 00:00:00' 
        and sv.timing <= timestamp '2018-02-02 23:59:59';
```

But if I remove the condition on timing and want to find out whole output, it misses one row which is between this time. Why is it happening? What is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT distinct on (st.gid) sv.timing, st.gid, st.area
    FROM servers sv
    INNER JOIN sites st
    ON (st_distance(sv.geom, st.geom)<8.5) where
            sv.workmode = 1;
```

Comment: is the *st.gid* of that on missing row unique? if that *st.gid* also exists outside of that time interval, it will be omitted due to the `DISTINCT ON (st.gid)`. unwanted advice: if it's only full days you´re after you could simplify by casting to *date*, i.e. `...AND sv.timing::date = '2018-02-02'`.

Comment: Thanks @ThingumaBob for your reply. st.gid of that missing row is unique. I checked. Additionally, my gid is the primary key, so, it is of course unique. Anyway thanks for the date search suggestion

Comment: thank you @ThingumaBob. As you mentioned the idea of unique or not, I found out that my whole query (without date condition) fulfills the criteria with that gid before reaching 2-2-2018. That's why it does not include again into 2-2-2018. But for the query with time condition it finds out as it also in that time too. Now I got the point. Thanks again, your way of investigation was the trick to find out.

Comment: yeah I guess we kind of mean the same thing ,) `DISTINCT ON` can sometimes be tricky...glad I could lead you to it.

Comment: Could you please write your observation as answer, so that i can accept it @ThingumaBob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely due to the `DISTINCT ON (st.gid)` command; if there are multiple entries for a single value in that column, e.g. for different *timestamps*, all but the first found row (if not further specified) containing that value will be filtered out.
By defining that time interval, you limit the possible rows to your desired range and thus guarantee it's occurence.